# backtrack on virtualbox not getting ip address

Tags: virtualbox, backtrack-linux

i am trying to use backtrack5 on my virtualbox and set my adapter to bridged so that backtrack can have connection to the internet. But its not getting an ip even though its requesting for one when ever it boots. I read on other forums that some dhcp servers are configured not to give more than one ip to one mac addrees.so I used ipconfig / release to release the host ip so that my guest can obtain an ip but still its not working.when I set the adapter to NAT, it picks up an IP address from VB no problem but that does not connect me to the internet. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may be due to the anti-virus ur using.try disabling it.